# Swing not showing gap between panels

Tags: java, swing

Here's my code:

```
button_panel = new JPanel();
        button_panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(button_panel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        button_panel.add(import_button);
        button_panel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
        button_panel.add(clear_button);
        button_panel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
        button_panel.add(generate_button);
        button_panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 5)));
        
        input_panel = new JPanel();
        input_panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(input_panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        input_box = new JTextArea(5,5);
        input_box.setLineWrap(true);
        input_box.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        input_scroll = new JScrollPane(input_box);
        input_label = new JLabel("Input");
        input_panel.add(input_label);
        input_panel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(30));
        input_panel.add(input_box);
        input_panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 5)));
        
        output_panel = new JPanel();
        output_panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(output_panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        output_box = new JTextArea(5, 5);
        output_box.setLineWrap(true);
        output_box.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        output_scroll = new JScrollPane(output_box);
        output_label = new JLabel("Output");
        output_panel.add(output_label);
        output_panel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));
        output_panel.add(output_box);
        output_panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 5)));

        this.panel.add(button_panel);
        this.panel.add(input_panel);
        this.panel.add(output_panel);
```

And here's the output:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkX8x.png]

The expected behavior is that there will be a gap between the buttons and the input section, and then another between the input section and the output section. Any ideas on where I could've gone wrong?

Comment: All three `JPanels` could be arranged with a `FlowLayout`.  You don't show the layout manager of the main `JPanel` that holds the three `JPanels`.  In my opinion, you're over-specifying the `BoxLayout`.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

Comment: You can use empty `JPanel` borders to create whitespace.